# Assertion Error for 3D kriging interpolation using GeoStats package in Julia

Tags: julia, interpolation, kriging

I am trying to build a kriging surface interpolation example using `GeoStats.jl` package.
I have supplied `x` and `y` coordinates as inputs and `z` coordinates as values to train the function. Then I try to predict the `z` values for other set of inputs.
The goal is to predict the topology interpolation, and the example code is mentioned below:

```
using GeoStats, DataFrames
using Variography, Plots

#create your interpolator object
OK = OrdinaryKriging(GaussianVariogram())

# fit it to the data:

x_train = [1.0,1.0,10.0,10.0,2.5,7.5] # x coordinates train
y_train = [1.0,10.0,10.0,1.0,5.0,5.0] # y coordinates train
z = [2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,4.5,4.5] # z coordinates train

table_train = DataFrame(:x=>x_train, :y=>y_train)

 = georef(table_train, [x y]')

scatter(, z, label="train points")

krig = KrigingEstimators.fit(OK, , z) # fit function

# predictions:

x_test = [1.5,1.5,11.0,11.0,3.5,5.5] # x coordinates test
y_test = [1.4,10.5,10.6,4.0,6.0,8.0] # y coordinates test

table_test = DataFrame(:xt=>x_test, :yt=>y_test)

test = georef(table, [xt yt]')

result = []
variance =[]

for i in test
    μ, σ² = KrigingEstimators.predict(krig, [i])
    push!(result, μ)
    push!(variance, σ²)
end
df_krig_vario = DataFrame(:predict=>result, :real=>y_test, :variance=>variance)
println(first(df_krig_vario, 5))
mean_var = sum(variance)/length(variance)
println("")
println("mean variance is $mean_var")
test = reshape(test, length(test), 1)
plot!(test, y_test, label="actual")
plot!(test, result, label="predict", legend=:bottomright, title="Gaussian Variogram")
```

However, when I run this code it throws the following error:

```
AssertionError: invalid variable name

Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion at C:\Users\User\.julia\packages\GeoStatsBase\aI9iy\src\plotrecipes\data.jl:14 [inlined]
 [2] apply_recipe(::AbstractDict{Symbol,Any}, ::AbstractData, ::Any) at C:\Users\User\.julia\packages\RecipesBase\92zOw\src\RecipesBase.jl:282
 [3] _process_userrecipes!(::Any, ::Any, ::Any) at C:\Users\User\.julia\packages\RecipesPipeline\VEk89\src\user_recipe.jl:36
 [4] recipe_pipeline!(::Any, ::Any, ::Any) at C:\Users\User\.julia\packages\RecipesPipeline\VEk89\src\RecipesPipeline.jl:70
 [5] _plot!(::Plots.Plot, ::Any, ::Any) at C:\Users\User\.julia\packages\Plots\KN96c\src\plot.jl:172
 [6] #plot#129 at C:\Users\User\.julia\packages\Plots\KN96c\src\plot.jl:58 [inlined]
 [7] scatter(::Any, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N; kw::Any) at C:\Users\User\.julia\packages\RecipesBase\92zOw\src\RecipesBase.jl:403
 [8] top-level scope at In[58]:18
 [9] include_string(::Function, ::Module, ::String, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1091
```

May I know how can I resolve this issue?

Thanks!